# How to install C++ API documentation in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux

I have already installed gcc.

for `man 2 cout`

```
root@kota-laptop:/# man 2 cout
No manual entry for cout in section 2

root@kota-laptop:/# man 2 printf
No manual entry for printf in section 2
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

Comment: FWIW the man page for `printf` is in section 3, not section 2, and there's no man page at all for `cout`.

Comment: additionally, standard C++ names are in the std namespace, so `man std::iostream` instead of `man iostream`

Answer (score 7):

Installing gcc does not bring in the developer manpages.

`sudo aptitude install manpages-dev manpages-posix-dev`

That will install the docs for POSIX and C development.

**Edit since Ubuntu's package listing website is weird**

For C++ docs, you can install the libstdc++6-4.3-doc package or libstdc++6-4.4-doc, depending on your installed GCC (hooray for obscure naming).

- 4.3: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B6-4.3-doc
- 4.4: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libstdc%2B%2B6-4.4-doc

I don't use Ubuntu, so I can only assume it's: `sudo aptitude install libstdc++6-4.4-doc`

**Edit the stuff below is crufty and left for reference**

<strike>However, Ubuntu does not have any C++ manpages for simple installation.</strike> For that, you will have to install the manpages yourself from GNU libstdc++ documentation, available at their FTP site: ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/libstdc++/doxygen/

You will want to download the ones suitable for your version of libstdc++.

Comment: root@kota-laptop:~# man 2 printf
No manual entry for printf in section 2
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.

Comment: @kot C's `printf` command is `man 3 printf`. Section 3 is reserved for C (and C++) functions. Section 2 is for system calls like  `stat` and `fork`.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use ubuntu as a development work station, your first stop shop should be:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

As @birryree noted, you might not get all the things you need, but this first step will save you some hassle later.